# Netlogo BehaviorSpace mean value after every repetition

Tags: netlogo, mean, behaviorspace

in BehaviorSpace I have ["concetration" 0 0.2 1] and for each value of concetration I have to make 1000 repetiotions, but I have to bring a mean value of ticks after those repetition, not any other value. Someone knows how to do this? So what I want in result is:

concetration = 0.0 <mean value of ticks after 1000 repetitions>

concetration = 0.2 <mean value of ticks after 1000 repetitions>

concetration = 0.4 <mean value of ticks after 1000 repetitions>

Answer (score 1):

`ticks` is the number of time steps that the simulation ran for. Does it end naturally (like an epidemic runs out) or do you stop it after a certain number of ticks? If you stop it after a fixed number of ticks, then the mean of ticks doesn't make sense.

Assuming that what you are asking is to calculate the average number of ticks that the simulation runs for before ending naturally (1) have BehaviorSpace just record the end of the simulation, not every step (2) look at the BehaviorSpace output and the variable [step] is the last step that the simulation did, which is also `ticks` if you have the normal setup / go structure.

Comment: Simulation ends naturally after random number of ticks.
I have [step] in output but what I mean is that those [step] is recordes 1000 times (number of repetitions) and what I want is mean value of ticks after 1000 repetitions

Comment: That value of [step] is the number of ticks take for one repetition. Your output should have 1000 repetitions, each with a value of [step] or ticks. So the average ticks is the average of those 1000 numbers.

Comment: what iI have now is:
concetration = 0.0 <num of ticks for repetition 1>
concetration = 0.0 <num of ticks for repetirion 2>
.
.
.
concetration = 0.0 <num of ticks for repetirion 1000>
concetration = 0.2 <num of ticks for repetirion 1> etc, and i want to have one mean value for every concetration after 1000 repetitions

Comment: This is not a BehaviorSpace question. That data is exported as a csv file. Open the csv file in whatever spreadsheet software you used and take the average of the 1000 repetitions (for each value of concentration). Or, try the different types of output from BehaviorSpace (try spreadsheet format instead of table)